# How to add "File Upload" field in Product module in suiteCRM?

Tags: file-upload, sugarcrm, suitecrm, custom-field-type

How to add "File Upload" field in Product module in **suiteCRM** ?

Answer (score 0):

Go in to admin -> studio -> products -> fields. Add a field and set the type to image. Then go into layouts and drag your new field into the edit view.